# Twig roles checking is redirect

Tags: symfony, security, twig, roles, symfony4

When I trying to check user roles in the Twig with `is_granted()` not return boolean just redirect to the login path.

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') == true %} # without == true tested.
        <a href="{{ path('foo_bar') }}">Foo Bar Link</a>
{% endif %}
```

Symfony: 4.1

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I need to check the role need to return boolean but now is redirect

Comment: Maybe the redirection comes from the Controller, can you show us ?

Comment: But without this part of code no redirect happens

Comment: You forgot the if keyword

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i forgot to write if here i will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Provided piece of code __does not redirect__ anywhere, unless there's some javascript magic that finds this `a` element and triggers a click.

Comment: Some things to try as steps to debug: 1. Try `{% if true %}` as your condition statement. 2. Try another defined role besides `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`. 3. Replace your `<a>` tag with something else, like a simple string.

Comment: @ehymel thanks but I will doing before asking the question but when user hasn't the role is_granted will redirect instead of return false

Comment: You tried all 3 of my suggestions? The redirect you mentioned is not coming from the code you posted alone. Something else is causing it.

Comment: @ehymel Yes sir when I try the "1" suggest it's ok and also when a user has the role and replace a with plain text but still redirect when the user has not ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN or any role the user has not.

Comment: If you remove the conditional statement altogether (just leave the `<a>` link does everything work as expected?

Comment: @ehymel yes it's true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180160/discussion-between-ehymel-and-a-seddighi).

Comment: @ehymel Thank you, sir. my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved when I change the Authenticator

before change:

```
 $isPasswordValid = $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $token->getCredentials());
 if ($isPasswordValid) {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
 }
```

and after change it to:

```
 $isPasswordValid = $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $token->getCredentials());
 if ($isPasswordValid or $token->getUser() instanceof User) {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
 }
```

I append `$token->getUser() instanceof User` to the conditation.

Comment: could you please check it for security bug?!

Comment: A.Seddighi need your help in symfony